# RabbitMq and KStreams for Data Aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to solve the problem of data denormalization before indexing to the Elasticsearch. Right now, my Postgres 11 database is configured with pgoutput plugin and Debezium with Postgresql Connector is streaming the log changes to RabbitMq which are then aggregated by doing a reverse lookup on the db and feeding to the Elasticsearch.

Although, this works okay, the lookup at the App layer to aggregate the data is expensive and taking a lot of execution time (the query is already refined but it has about 10 joins making it sloppy).

The other alternative I explored was to use KStreams for data aggregation. My knowledge on Apache Kafka is minimal and thus I'm here. My question here is it a requirement to have Apache Kafka as the broker to be able to utilize the Java KStreams API or can it be leveraged with any broker such as RabbitMq? I'm unsure about this because all the articles talk about Kafka Topics and Key Value pairs which are specific to Apache Kafka.

If there is a better way to solve the data denormalization problem, I'm open to it too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Steams is only for Kafka. You're more than welcome to use Kafka Streams between Debezium and the process that consumes any topic (the Postgres connector that writes to RabbitMQ?)

You can use Spark, Flink, or Beam for stream processing on other messaging queues, but Debezium requires Kafka so start with tools around that.

Spark, for example, has an Elasticsearch writer library; not sure about the others.

Comment: I'm using a standalone Debezium-Server with a custom RabbitMq sink which allows to stream log messages without Kafka. My existing application is all tied with RabbitMq and it doesn't really make sense to add another broker just for this use-case. So is it not possible to send messages with RabbitMq and use KStreams on the Consumer?

Comment: Like I said, Kafka Streams cannot work with anything except Kafka. I haven't used Debezium standalone server, but it seems like it is just a one-to-one process that uses the Kafka Connect libraries to do simple record transformations and filtering between systems without requiring a broker (or the broker is embedded). Therefore, you need one of the other tools I mentioned to do aggregations.

Comment: Maybe it is useful to say: RabbitMQ has a Stream queue that works similar to Kafka. https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio Thanks, but the question seems to be asking how to to do lookups and aggregates against databases from events, not RabbitMQ features specifically